# How to use Firebase invisible reCAPTCHA for angular web app?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hoping to see a working example. Searched quite a bit, can't seem to get it working locally. Always shows privacy terms logo & user has to interact with captcha.

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/alphalink/pen/oGRzNz?editors=1010) I've created to speed things up.

From the [Firebase-Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#use-invisible-recaptcha):

> Use invisible reCAPTCHA
>
> To use an invisible reCAPTCHA, create a RecaptchaVerifier object with the size parameter set to invisible, specifying the ID of the button that submits your sign-in form.

```js
window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('sign-in-button', {
  'size': 'invisible',
  'callback': function(response) {
    // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
    onSignInSubmit();
  }
});
```

Basically what I have in this views on init:

```js
window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('phone-sign-in-recaptcha', {
  'size': 'invisible',
  'callback': function(response) {
    // reCAPTCHA solved - will proceed with submit function
    console.log(response);
  },
  'expired-callback': function() {
    // Reset reCAPTCHA?
  }
});
```

```html
<form name="mobile" novalidate>
  <label class="item item-input">
    <i class="icon placeholder-icon"></i>
    <input type="tel" name="number" ng-model="$ctrl.user.mobile">
  </label>
  <button id="sign-in-button" ng-click="$ctrl.onSignInSubmit(user.mobile)"></button>
</form>
<div id="phone-sign-in-recaptcha"></div>
```

This is the function called on submit:

```js
ctrl.onSignInSubmit = function() {
  var phoneNumber = '+1' + ctrl.user.mobile;
  var appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;

  firebase.auth()
    .signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
    .then(function(confirmationResult) {
      ctrl.hasCodeToVerify = true;
      console.log('confirmationResult', confirmationResult);
      window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log('error', error);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a working example with invisible reCAPTCHA:

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/auth/phone-invisible.html

In your code, after you call `signInWithPhoneNumber`, invisible reCAPTCHA should either display a challenge which when solved, resolves the pending promise with the `confirmationResult`, or directly resolves without showing any challenge.

When that promise resolves with `confirmationResult`, you should ask the user for the SMS code.
You then call `confirmationResult.confirm(code)`
This will complete sign in of the user.

```
firebase
  .auth()
  .signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
  .then(function(confirmationResult) {
    var code = window.prompt("Please enter your code");
    return confirmationResult.confirm(code);
  })
  .then(function(result) {
    // User is signed in now.
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("error", error);
  });
```

Comment: I had taken a look at that quick start, it has a render method I'm not sure if its suppose to actually render the challenge or autocomplete it. i tried using it in my code. Either not usuing it correctly or not going to solve the challenge. Ill make a codepen so maybe you/other can help through there.

Comment: I've seen your posts on other firebase and ionic questions. seems like this has something to do with originating URL. most of them get an HTTP error message, with the invisible captcha.

Comment: Hey @alphapilgrim, you don't seem to ask the user for the SMS code. I added a simple example showing how to do this.

Comment: quite right @bojeil! I had the confirmation in a different function with different click event. Thank you so much! I was about to remove this piece from the app.